# firebasex error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am making an Ionic app and I want to integrate cordova plugin firebase. Unfortunately, this plugin is not maintained anymore so I use a fork: firebasex.

When running "ionic cordova run android", I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 43s
C:\[...]\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: C:\[...]\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine\SystemCookieManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\[...]\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePlugin.java:405: error: cannot find symbol
                    boolean areNotificationsEnabled = notificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled();
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   method areNotificationsEnabled()
  location: variable notificationManagerCompat of type NotificationManagerCompat
C:\[...]\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\firebase\FirebasePluginMessagingService.java:204: error: constructor Builder in class Builder cannot be applied to given types;
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
                                                             ^
  required: Context
  found: FirebasePluginMessagingService,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

I have tried everything: removing and adding back android platform, use androidx, reinstalling modules etc etc.

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.3 (C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 16 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : 0.2.8

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\[...]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Cordova version:

```
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "me",
  "homepage": "page.com",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/base64": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^5.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-picker": "^5.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/media-capture": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.10.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/streaming-media": "^5.9.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "com-badrit-base64": "0.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-support-v4": "^21.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepicker": "1.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-streaming-media": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "5.4.7",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-streaming-media": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {},
      "com-badrit-base64": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-android-support-v4": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity and people just like me searching 'firebase-x boolean areNotificationsEnabled = notificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled();', the answer is @mobiemp 's comment re android v4.

Simply remove it:

```
# ionic users
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-android-support-v4
# cordova users
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-android-support-v4

cordova clean android; # flush it out

# then use your run command again, ie 
ionic cordova run android  -lc  --address=0.0.0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove firebase plugin if it is still there... also you need to update firebasex... it will fix the problem... if it isn't then trying removing some deprecated plugins you will able to find out in which plugin the problem exists...
it is the problem with the plugin the error message indicating that point. the similar problem exists with other plugins and update of the plugin and removing of the plugin fix the error...

here is the [reference](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-failed-after-updating-cordova-6-4/114701/10)

Comment: Firebase is already uninstalled and firebasex is up to date... What else could it be?

Comment: disable both of them and try to make build... if it solves the problem that means there was a problem with that plugin... 

cordova-plugin-camera, cordova-plugin-geolocation cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0 --save

Comment: check list of plugins using command ionic cordova plugin list it will show the plugin list with versions... then you can see the version and check out which plugin is not up to date...

Comment: I finally found it was plugin support android v4 which was in conflict. I removed it and now it works!